# evaluating the integral $\int \frac{e^x(x^4+2)dx}{(x^2+1)^{5/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

It accidentally came out like this but I need a fine proof for it.
$$\int e^x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)+\dfrac{x}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}\right) dx$$

I am unable to figure out why $$\int\dfrac{1-2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{5/2}}dx =\dfrac{x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^{3/2}}$$ (It comes in the middle of solving)

Please give hints on how to solve it.

Comment: @mickep I updated it. Please see.

Comment: I would have said "partial fractions", but the solution on Wolfram Alpha says $$\int \frac{1-2x^2}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}} \;\text{d}x = \frac{3x}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}} - 2\sinh^{-1}(x) + C$$ Are you sure you've copied it right?

Comment: @Maximilian Gerhardt Sorry, a mistake. I changed it. Please see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to find a way to show:

> $$\int\frac{1-2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{5/2}} \,\mbox{d}x =\dfrac{x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^{3/2}}$$

Let $x = \tan t$, then:
$$\int\dfrac{1-2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{5/2}} \,\mbox{d}x \to \int\dfrac{1-2\tan^2t}{\left(1+\tan^2t\right)^{5/2}} \sec^2 t \,\mbox{d}t$$

Now use $1+\tan^2 = \sec^2t$ and simplify:

$$\int\dfrac{1-2\tan^2t}{\sec^3 t}  \,\mbox{d}t 
= \int \cos t \left( 1-3\sin^2 t \right) \,\mbox{d}t =\sin t - \sin^3t + C$$
First rewrite (this will make it easier to substitute back and simplify):
$$\sin t - \sin^3t = \sin t \left( 1 - \sin^2t \right)  = \sin t\cos^2t$$
Now you can substitute $t = \arctan x$ again and simplify:
$$\sin \left( \arctan x \right) \left( \cos \left( \arctan x \right) \right)^2 = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \right)^2 = \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}$$